# Apple Web Push Notification Signing. What is intermediate certificate?

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to sign my push package for Apple Web Push Notification by following instructions

[Apple Web Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html)

In `Signature` section, it says to sign using using private key for web push certificate (obtainable from MAC keychain) but it also says that it needs to be signed by `Intermediate Certificate` as well.

**Where can I obtain this intermediate certificate?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Developers who provide passes for Apple Wallet, deliver Safari Push
>   Notifications, create Safari Extensions or submit apps to the App
>   Store, Mac App Store, or App Store for Apple TV need to download the renewed certificate

You need the [Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) which you can directly download here [here](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)